# Discord.py bot - detect when a user does a hybrid command

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a hybrid command () used to start a game. When it is first run from one user, it asks a second user to run the same command to start the game and waits for that input.

The code runs fine if the second user does !turbotype to start the game, but not if they do it as a slash command (/tubotype ).

```
 @commands.hybrid_command(name='turbotype')
    async def turbotype(self, ctx): 

       original_channel = ctx.channel
     await original_channel.send(f"_ _ \n{ctx.author.mention} wants to start a Turbo Type game! \nWhoever wants to challenge me, do: **!turbotype** in the server: **Heart-to-Heart**")

       try: # waits for the second player to join

                player2_message = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=10, check=lambda m: m.author != ctx.author and (m.content.lower().startswith('!turbotype') or m.content.lower().startswith('/turbotype '))) # player 2 has to join by doing !turbotype or the slash command
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a button for the 2nd player to join instead of a different player running the slash command. Otherwise, you might have to save which channels have a game running to check whether it's the 2nd player that runs the command or the first.